# TextBox tipo texto a Entero

Tags: vb.net, formularios, conversión-de-tipos

Deseo insertar este formulario en una DB en sql server.

[image: Interfaz]

Pero por el momento como todos están txt no me deja ingresar por los campos que son enteros

[image: asignación de cajas de texto]

como lo convierto a entero, algo así como parseint

- Me salta esta advertencia y si le coloco integer me dice caracter no
  valido. Voy a probar primero alcenandola como la tenia luego eso que
  almacene parsearlo.

[image: Advetencia]

Te confirmo con esta imagen que estoy usando VS y aparte me pregunto porque esta vez sale este error, no veo que envíe valores nulos, y anteriormente fue por los ; demás

[image: confirmacion y error]

Comment: ¿Puedes confirmar que estás usando VB.NET?

Comment: @sstan con la ultima imagen te confirmo que uso vs

Comment: Según la última imágen que pusistes, parece que resolvistes el problema. Ahora tienes un problema diferente, por lo que si necesitas ayuda para esta también, lo correcto es abrir una nueva pregunta, ya que la pregunta no es la misma.

Comment: ok muchas gracias

Comment: @ViceteGeovannyFrancoSiles el error de la última imagen es porque no estás ingresando nada en `Olimpiadas1.participantes` columna `dpi`. La conversión de texto a entero lo ha respondido el usuario sstan.

Comment: @Mauricio es verdad que sstan respondió correctamente, puedes explicarme mejor, en la imagen dice 4 puntos, y tu me dices que en el cuarto no estoy agregando, puedes explicarte un poco mejor. Yo entiendo que todo lo estoy agregando a registro que es una variable privada **Private registro As OlimpiadasDS.participantesRow** y luego lo mando a mi adaptador para actualizarse

Comment: dentro de 30 min puedo hacer la otra pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como pareces estar usando VB.NET, puedes usar [`Integer.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ejemplo:

```
Me.registro.edad = Integer.Parse(txtedad.Text)
```

Comment: si es sin punto y coma pero ahora me salta que envió parámetros nulos

Answer (score 0):

Usa [int.parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Ejemplo:

```
Me.registro.edad = int.Parse(txtedad.Text);
```

Revisa la siguiente [referencia en MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx) para mas información.

Comment: me salta una advertencia agrego la imagen para que la veas

Comment: @ViceteGeovannyFrancoSiles por favor aclara si estás usando VB.NET así como [comenta el usuario sstan](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35959/textbox-tipo-texto-a-entero/35960?noredirect=1#comment60295_35959)

Comment: mi versión es Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 es el entorno de desarrollo, el **lenguaje de programación** que esás usando es VB.NET.

Comment: gracias por la aclaración, @Mauricio